# Execute Vlookup if an IF condition is satisfied

Tags: vba, excel, if-statement, excel-formula, vlookup

I am trying to run a loop with vlookup, if an IF condition is met. I have written the code provided below but it gives an error in error in line 3 saying type mismatch. lastrow and ws1 are well defined as I have managed to run this code without the if condition. I am providing both the code that managed to run without the if condition and the code that does not run

**CODE 1 (It runs but does not have a `If` condition)**

```
With ws1
    .Range("G2:G" & lastrow3).Formula = "=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(C2,'[NOT OK.xlsx]Sheet1'!F:I,4,FALSE),"""")"
    .Range("G2:G" & lastrow3).Value = .Range("G2:G" & lastrow3).Value
End With
```

**CODE 2 (It does not run)**

```
With ws1
    For i = 2 To lastrow3
        If .Cells(i, "E").Value = 0 And .Cells(i, "F").Value = 0 Then
        .Cells(i, "G").Formula = "=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(C2,'[NOT OK.xlsx]Sheet1'!F:I,4,FALSE),"""")"
        End If
    Next i
End With
```

Comment: should .Cells(i, "E").Value be .Cells("E", i).Value etc

Comment: it still wont work

Comment: Do you have any error values in cells?

Comment: No , I have removed them.. they are either 0 or >0

Comment: Have you stepped through? What is the value of lastrow3?

Comment: Yes I have stepped through... the value is 433.. the issue is reognising the value of the cells with 0

Comment: Your Lastrow3 value is probably less then 2, assuming E2 and  F2 are 0

Comment: ++ just a tip: avoid IFERROR

Comment: I am afraid that there is no other option than that it really meets some error value, because you could have only type mismatch on i if it wasnt number, but that would show error in line 2 or on the whole value if it meets error.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like i cant read.

```
with ws1
    For i = 2 To 6
        If .Cells(i, "E").Value = 0 And .Cells(i, "F").Value = 0 Then
            .Cells(i, "G").Value = "ok"
        End If
    Next i
end with
```

runs fine and produces.

[image]

Also the hardcoded `C2` in the search string of VLOOKUP is probably not wanted.

Comment: yes, for me does the same. You could have kept the info about C2 being hard coded as that was valid and the vlookup is quite useless as it is now in the question.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just use an IF formula like

```
IF(E2+F2 = 0, VLOOKUP(C2,'[NOT OK.xlsx]Sheet1'!F:I,4,FALSE), "")

Used in VBA like this:

For I = 2 To lastRow
   Range("G" & I).Formula = "=IF(E" & I & "+ F" & I & " = 0, " & Chr(34) & "VLOOKUP(C2,'[NOT OK.xlsx]Sheet1'!F:I,4,FALSE)" & Chr(34) & ", " & Chr(34) & "No" & Chr(34) & ")"
 Next I
```